# Correctly substitute values for working with ImageGrab

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

How can I change the format of a string so that ImageGrab accepts it?

My task is to get the coordinates for the container from the file and paste their values into the box.

There is only one line in the file and it has the format: `335,50,467,70`.

If I substitute these values directly, and not through a variable, the script works perfectly. But he refuses to take values from the file.

What do i do?

```
    from PIL import ImageGrab

    with open(r"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\area.txt", "r") as file:
        lines = file.readline()
        print(lines)
        box = (lines)
        #box = (335,50,467,70)     # If so, then everything works perfectly
        print(box)
        img = ImageGrab.grab(box) 
        #img.show()
```

Comment: `.readline()` will give a string "335,50,467,70". You need to cast this to a tuple of ints.

Comment: Yes. I tried to do something level box = (int(lines)) or box = (list(lines)), but it ended in failure. Maybe I'm thinking wrong. I am pretty new to python. @QuantumChris

Comment: Trying to cast all of `"335,50,467,70"` to an int directly won't work because it's actually several comma-separated ints. Instead, you need to do something like: `box = tuple(int(item) for item in lines.split(','))`

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you very much!
Answer so that I can choose you the best and thank you for your help. @QuantumChris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment a little, you have a string: `lines = "335,50,467,70"`

You can split the string by separating across the commas to give a list of strings, like so:

```py
box = lines.split(',')
box
>>> ["335", "50", "467", "70"]
```

Then, you can iterate over the list and cast each item to an int like so:

```py
box = tuple(int(item) for item in lines.split(','))
box
>>> (335, 50, 467, 70)
```